# how i can avoid No document found on my subcollection with firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a simple query on my subcollection. I want all the members with the user id . But i have no document found. I'm supposed to have One team available on my model .

```
GetMesTeams = async () => {
   firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      .doc()
      .collection("membersList")
      .where("id", "==", "PTbEn2fba0QudXI8JE8RioQ9of53")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found validé");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let valid = doc._data;
            console.log("validé", valid);
          });
        }
      });
}
```

Did i forget something ?

Comment: You need to specify the team ID in the `.collection("teams").doc()`

Comment: and if i want to catch all the document on this collection ?

Comment: So you want to fetch the members List from all teams?

Comment: exactly i want to query all the document of the subbcollection's Team

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your database? It's confusing what that ID is about.

Comment: it's ok , i resolve my problem to start by get my collection then i used the doc.id of my collection to query my subcollection :)